# Crash When Removing Self as Observer - CALayer

Tags: objective-c, macos, key-value-observing

I am having a crash in my CALayer subclass when I remove myself as an observer in -(void)dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"showColorLabels"];
 [colorLabel release];
 [_color release];
 [super dealloc];
}
```

An exception is thrown. It says that self has not been added as an observer. This only happens in a certain case, after [CATransaction flush] is called.

I used Instruments to see when the object was allocated. It says it was allocated with the call CALayerGetPresentationLayer(). I am not sure how this works, but I guess this is a copy of my original layer, so init was never called, and I was never added as an observer.

How can I either check that I am an observer before removing myself, or maybe tell if I am a presentation layer?

Bridger Maxwell

Answer (score 2):

I found a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714561/958017

you can use a try-catch block in your call to removeobserver:

```
@try{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"showColorLabels"];
}@catch(id anException){
   //Whatever you want to do.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welllll.... to ask the obvious question in response:

*Where are you adding `self` as an observer of the `@"showColorLabels` key?*

You shouldn't have to invoke `-removeObserver:forKeyPath:` unless you explicitly added the object as an observer in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I added myself as an observer in my init method. I think the problem is that when a copy of my layer is made my init method isn't called.

Comment: That would definitely be an issue;  you should override `-copy` to set up the observers appropriately.