# KVO versus NSNotifications

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-observing

Is there any advantage to use KVO instead of the more "generic" (and to my opion more robust) feature of `NSNotification`s ?

Comment: What bit of KVO do you find to not be robust?

Comment: The downsides are nicely discussed in the [Cocoa Builder link](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/167622-kvo-and-the-observevalueforkeypath-bottleneck.html) I gave in my answer. Mostly the problems stem from the fact that you have to handle all the KVO notifications in a single function, which is brittle when subclassing.

Comment: OK, i'd have to disagree with that. KVO isn't brittle when subclassing - using a Selector as the Context is a hack and not what it is for.

Comment: How about `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` which does not take any context? What if both my class and its subclass want to observe the same path and stop observing at different moments?

Comment: @hooleyhoop I don't mind the single handler, but [keeping track of whether I'm observing an object is annoying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582383/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-has-a-key-value-observer-attached#comment19002543_1582597). I still use KVO, but if there was an automatic reference counting (ARC) version of KVO, I'd probably use it.

Comment: Update: In iOS 6 and later, `viewDidUnload` isn't called anymore. So now, we can begin observing in `viewDidLoad` and end observing in `deinit`, knowing that the calls to each method are one-to-one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hate KVO with passion, mainly because it forces me to route all KVO notifications through a single handler. I use whatever else available if I have the choice. But KVO has the distinct advantage of being available for many of the classes in the standard library – if you want to observe property changes on some classes from the standard library, KVO might be your only option. There is one [very interesting thread on Cocoa Builder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/167622-kvo-and-the-observevalueforkeypath-bottleneck.html) about KVO and various observing and binding options.

(I should add that I only have gripes with KVO as a high-level observation interface. I think it’s very good as plumbing for other technologies, especially bindings.)

Answer (score 5):

In order to use NSNotifications todo something similar to KVO you would have to write custom boilerplate accessor methods for every property you wanted to observe.

This is both much less "generic" and much less robust than using KVO.